# There is no create new database option in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am starting to deploy my php web application to real server. So I bought a personal hosting plan from Arvixe with C Panel access. Then I logged in to C Panel and opened phpmyadmin to import my database. But when I try to create new database, there is no option for creating database in UI. As you can see below.

[image]

I also tried to create database from SQL command. But it is giving me error.

This is the error.

> #1044 - Access denied for user 'cpses_mmIulTbTrI'@'localhost' to database 'mmfashion'

Why is that happening and how can I create database in phpMyAdmin? How can I enable that feature?

Comment: check the privileges the account (`cpses_mmIulTbTrI`), it seems that you don't have the permission to create new database.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[image]

For cPanel you have to create a Database from MySQL Databases option.
You can not make a database directly from PHPMyAdmin (for cPanel Only).

**Step 1**: Make a database

**Step 2**: Make a database user

**Step 3**: Assign a user to that database

Then you done.

Comment: Thanks you. It helped me,

Comment: Always here to help